# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'lstCivil'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

En mi Controlador tengo un listado en un vector sencillo

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var lstEstadoCivil = new SelectList(new[]
        {
            new { ID = 1, Name = "Soltero" },
            new { ID = 2, Name = "Casado" },
            new { ID = 3, Name = "Viudo" },
        },
        "ID", "Name", 1);

        ViewData["lstCivil"] = lstEstadoCivil;

        ViewData["fechaActual"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        return View();
    }
```

y la vista de create se encuentra de este modo...

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownList("lstCivil", ViewData["lstCivil"] as SelectList)


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

en control dropdownlist ya he cambiado a as IEnumerable pero aun asi sale error en ese punto.

si hay alguien que me pueda colaborar les agradeceria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que simplemente utilizas un list, no es lo mas elegante (seria como agregar un Enumerable) para una solución pero te propongo que realizar de esta forma:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EstadoCivil",
          new List<SelectListItem>
          {
              new SelectListItem { Text= "Soltero", Value =  "1"},
              new SelectListItem { Text ="Casado", Value = "2"  },
              new SelectListItem { Text ="Viudo", Value = "3" }
          },
              "Seleccionar Estado Civil", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Veo que son pocos los items que tienes lo haces directamente desde la vista y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta del lado del controller cambiar tu lista por esto:

```
     var lstEstadoCivil = new SelectList(new[]
           {
                new { ID = 1, Name = "Soltero" },
                new { ID = 2, Name = "Casado" },
                new { ID = 3, Name = "Viudo" },
            },
         "ID", "Name", 1);

        ViewBag.lstCivil = lstEstadoCivil;
        //ViewData["lstCivil"] = lstEstadoCivil;

        ViewData["fechaActual"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        return View();
```

y del lado del cshtml lo siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownList("lstCivil", (SelectList)ViewBag.lstCivil,"selecione...")


                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

con eso debe funcionar!
Saludos!

Comment: porque al guardar el value lo necesito numerico, es ahi donde necesito que guarde numerico

Comment: Te acabo de editar la respuesta, espero con esta forma te funcione, saludos!

Comment: puedes intentar el cast como te lo propuse o con la forma en que tu lo tienes, no debería originar ningun problema, solo verifica que tu controller esté entrando y llenando la lista antes de entrar a la vista porque de lo contrario es posible que el código del controller no se esté ejecutando y al pasar por esa parte  detecta la lista en null y causa ese error